# WooCommerce add class name in the list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently, I am trying to customise the override WooCommerce.php file. Now, in this file,

```
<section id="content woocommerce" class="grid-block woocommerce">
<ul id="products" class="subcategory-products products">
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
</ul>
</section>
```

The output likes:

```
<li class="post-15 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock">
    <a href="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/product/i-phone-ai-template/">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/iphone-ai-template-150x150.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="iphone-ai-template">
        <h3>I-Phone Vector Template</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">$2</span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="/?add-to-cart=15" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="15" data-product_sku="ai-iphone" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is to change the class name, currently the class name is `post-15 product ...`. I would like to change the class name to product category.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular hook available to deal with classes in products list.
Therefore, we need to edit, "content-product.php" present in, "template" folder of "woocommerce" plugin.

We can add following code:

```
$product_id = get_the_ID();
$result = wp_get_post_terms($product_id,'product_cat');

    if(!empty($result)){

        $term = '';

        foreach($result as $single_result)
        {
            $term .= ' ' . $single_result->slug;
        }

        $classes[] = $term;
    }
```

after,

```
$classes = array();
```

statement.

This will result in the following output:

```
<ul class="products">
<li class="post-246 product type-product status-publish hentry general first sale instock">
<li class="post-33 product type-product status-publish hentry sale instock">
<li class="post-244 product type-product status-publish hentry general special sale instock">
</ul>
```

where, "General" and "Special" are categories.

Here I am fetching, product categories slugs and appending it to products class.